# How to generate a Rc<T> from &T in rust?

Tags: rust

To learn about Weak ref in Rust, I wrote the following code. The main thing is a Factory and a Car. use a Factory to weak ref to some of the cars it produces, and these Car always ref to the Factory that produced it.

Now I want to implement a `Factory.make_car()` function that creates a car object that implements the above reference relationship.

But while writing this function, I ran into a difficulty. Because the parameter of `make_car()` is a `&mut` of Factory object, how can I get the `Rc<Factory>` object?

That is, how to modify the following `????`  so that the program can compile successfully?

```rust
struct Factory {
    cars: Vec<Weak<Car>>,
}

struct Car {
    fact: Rc<Factory>,
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn make_car(&mut self) -> Car {
        let car = Car { fact: Rc::clone(???), };
        let carc = Rc::new(car);
        self.cars.push(Rc::downgrade(&carc));
        return car;
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_make_car() {
        let mut factory = super::Factory{cars: vec![]};
        let car = factory.make_car();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't return an owned car while keeping an `Rc<Car>` of the same instance. If the caller drops their instance, how would the `Rc` be able to track it. I think this goes for anything. You can have multiple cloned `Rc<T>` instances or a single `T`, not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't generate an `Rc<T>` from `&T`. To get `Rc<T>`, you either need to call `Rc::new()` on a `T` (which will allocate the space on the heap and move `T` there) or clone an existing `Rc` (which will increment the refcount and give you a new pointer to the existing storage). Given just a `&T` which might not even be inside an `Rc` (it could be stack-allocated, or inside a struct field or in a Box or a Vec, you get the idea), it's impossible to create an `Rc<T>`.

What you are trying to achieve is ultimately possible, but will require significant changes in the interface and the implementation, some of which you might find uncomfortable:

1. A `Factory` can only ever exist inside an `Rc` - otherwise a car won't be able to hold a `Rc<Factory>`. You can introduce a `new()` constructor that just returns `Rc<Factory>`, so you never even obtain a bare `Factory`.
2. That means that, in order to modify it, you have to introduce interior mutability, i.e. change the `cars` field from `Vec<X>` to `RefCell<Vec<X>>`.
3. With that in place, `make_car()` should accept `self: &Rc<Factory>`, which will allow a simple `factory.make_car()` to work (given that `factory` is only available inside `Rc` to begin with, ensured in #1).
4. `make_car()` cannot return `Car` because `Car` was moved inside the `Rc`. It must return `Rc<Car>` instead, which also ensures that the weak reference will stay live. (Destroying `Rc<Car>` inside the function would immediately kill the weak reference, which is probably not what you intended.)

With the above changes applied, the code could look like this:

```
struct Factory {
    cars: RefCell<Vec<Weak<Car>>>,
}

struct Car {
    fact: Rc<Factory>,
}

impl Factory {
    fn new() -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new(Factory {
            cars: RefCell::new(vec![]),
        })
    }

    pub fn make_car(self: &Rc<Factory>) -> Rc<Car> {
        let car = Rc::new(Car { fact: self.clone() });
        self.cars.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(&car));
        return car;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d625f9a90d6073a2ef225d962a470330)

Comment: Note that using `RefCell` is important here. It is what provides the `borrow_mut()` on cars. Using `cars: Vec<Weak<Car>>` would not allow updating the cars vector as it is only read only references. `RefCell` adds the functionality for mutation.